# How to convert simple form submit to ajax call;

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a form with input field which can be accessed like

```
var algorithm = document.forms["algoForm"]["algorithm"].value;
var input = document.forms["algoForm"]["input"].value;
```

and earlier call was

```
document.forms["algoForm"].submit();
```

and form was

```
<form name="algoForm" method="post" action="run.do">
```

It all run fine
Now I wanted convert it to the ajax call so that I can use the returned data from java code on the same page. So I used soemthing like

```
        var algorithm = document.forms["algoForm"]["algorithm"].value;
        var input = document.forms["algoForm"]["input"].value;
        var data = 'algorithm = ' + algorithm + '&input = ' + input;


    $.ajax(
            {
                url: "run.do",
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                success: onSuccess(tableData) 
                { //line 75
                    alert(tableData);
                }

            }
        );
```

However the above code doesn't run. Please help me make it run

Comment: First of all use the jQuery serialize http://api.jquery.com/serialize/ to convert your form data to "text string in standard URL-encoded notation"

Comment: Do you recieve some js erros?

Comment: And can you post the javascript error or the console log here?

Comment: @ArashMilani: yes I have to use that I'll try.

Comment: @veer7 Please use the  jQuery serialize and update your question :)

Comment: @ArashMilani : the error message is Webpage error details

User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET CLR 4.0.20506)
Timestamp: Mon, 18 Jun 2012 12:19:08 UTC


Message: Expected '}'
Line: 75
Char: 6
Code: 0
URI: file:///E:/DineshDocs/FromNilesh/dinesh/menu1.html


Message: Object expected
Line: 105
Char: 1
Code: 0
URI: file:///E:/DineshDocs/FromNilesh/dinesh/menu1.html

Comment: Shouldn't your line:74 be like this: `success: function(tableData) {`

Comment: I have posted the complete code as an answer. take a look @veer7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how but this one runs well,

```
    var algorithm = document.forms["algoForm"]["algorithm"].value;
    var input = document.forms["algoForm"]["input"].value;

    $.post('run.do', {  
            algorithm  : algorithm,
            input      : input
        }, function(data) {                  
            alert(data);
        }
    );
```

Answer (score 15):

Let's use jQuery's `serialize` to get the data out of the `form` and then use the jQuery's `ajax` function to send the data to the server:

```
var data = $("form[name=algoForm]").serialize();
$.ajax({
    url: "run.do",
    type: "POST",
    data: data,
    success: function(tableData){
        alert(tableData);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it  var data = $("form[name=algoForm]").serialize();  ?  Do I need include any files?

Comment: The only thing you need is jQuery library.

Comment: Yeah I'm pretty sure that line should work fine if your form's name is "algoForm" as you posted above.

Answer (score 5):

`data` expects a literal object, so you need:

```
var data = {
    'algorithm': algorithm,
    'input': input
};
```

Comment: The current version of jQuery ([documentation for `ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), as of Jun '15) allows the value of the `data` parameter to be a string, and is in fact converted to a URL-safe string if it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

**Instead of retrieving all the parameter value and then sending them separately (which can be done server side as well, using below code)**, Use this:

```
var $form = $("#divId").closest('form');
    data = $form.serializeArray();

    jqxhr = $.post("SERVLET_URL', data )
        .success(function() {
            if(jqxhr.responseText != ""){
                //on response
            }
        });
    }
```

`divId` is id of the div containing this form.

This code will send all the form parameters to your servlet. Now you can use request.getParameter in your servlet to get all the individual fields value on your servlet.

You can easily convert above jquery post to jquery ajax.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
// patching FORM - the style of data handling on server can remain untouched
$("#my-form").on("submit", function(evt) {
 var data = {};
 var $form = $(evt.target);
 var arr = $form.serializeArray(); // an array of all form items
 for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++) { // transforming the array to object
  data[arr[i].name] = arr[i].value;
 }
 data.return_type = "json"; // optional identifier - you can handle it on server and respond with JSON instead of HTML output
 $.ajax({
  url: $form.attr('action') || document.URL, // server script from form action attribute or document URL (if action is empty or not specified)
  type: $form.attr('method') || 'get', // method by form method or GET if not specified
  dataType: 'json', // we expect JSON in response
  data: data // object with all form items
 }).done(function(respond) {
  console.log("data handled on server - response:", respond);
  // your code (after saving)

 }).fail(function(){
  alert("Server connection failed!");
 });
 
 return false; // suppress default submit action
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```